# Get Physical Address(MAC) of Local LAN Networks without using IP in C#

Tags: c#

I am Building a Program that show Local Host Computer Names which are Connected with me. Actually, I also want to check their MAC(Physical Addresses) in List View. See this Image:
[image]

Now, You can see that My program is showing the Available Networks but Not showing physical Address. I want help that when I click on Show button, program automatic give Available Networks name with MAC.
I have searched on Internet so much but I can't Understand that How to show Mac address without using IP.
Now, there are many codes in this website but I can't found the right code.
And Sorry for my English, it is not so good.

Comment: On Which OS ? Show your code to get Computer Names

Comment: This is for Windows 8 or 7 and Computer Names Codes in too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without Ip address you cannot find the MAC of other computers unless software is installed on those individual computers.

If want MAC of a system :

```
   public string GetMacAddress(string ipAddress)
{
    string macAddress = string.Empty;
    System.Diagnostics.Process pProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    pProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "arp";
    pProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-a " + ipAddress;
    pProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
      pProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    pProcess.Start();
    string strOutput = pProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    string[] substrings = strOutput.Split('-');
    if (substrings.Length >= 8)
    {
       macAddress = substrings[3].Substring(Math.Max(0, substrings[3].Length - 2)) 
                + "-" + substrings[4] + "-" + substrings[5] + "-" + substrings[6] 
                + "-" + substrings[7] + "-" 
                + substrings[8].Substring(0, 2);
        return macAddress;
    }

    else
    {
        return "not found";
    }
}
```

Comment: Suppose, If I have IP of target computer then How I will get that computer MAC Address?